# Making a button which on press or click executive a function until unpress the buttons

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

Here the thing I m trying to make an object move using HTML button but in click it exicute the function ones I want it to exicute the function continuously on press of button
Below is the code for the button in JavaScript

```
var increment = 1; 

function moveUp()
{
camera.position.z +=increment;
}
function moveDown()
{
camera.position.z -= increment;
}
function moveRight()
{
camera.position.x +=increment;
}
function moveLeft()
{
camera.position.x -= increment;
}
```

Comment: use `setInterval`, create a timer, store the return value/id from and when you click/press the button again user `clearInterval` to clear/terminate the execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the events.

1. Detect the keyDown event. Set a variable 'buttonUpIsDown'=true and call -or set a timer to call every 10ms- a function.
2. While/If (buttonUpIsDown) { increment stuff};
3. Detect the keyUp event and put the variable back to false.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent